# RAID setup for high speed reading

Tags: linux, raid, performance

We are looking to build a realtime playback machine using Linux and a RAID (5 or 10) setup. The current setup looks like:

- 12GB memory
- 5 x 7200rpm drive (software raid)
- centOS 6 (Kernel Linux 2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64)
- NVidia Quadro 5000 (driver 280.13)
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650  @ 2.67GHz

I did run Bonnie++ and iozone to do some benchmark with different raid setup (5 and 10), with
different fs type (ext4 and xfs), and different stripe size. Unfortunately it seems that I can't
get the speed I want out of it (always <200MB/s).

The other test I made was directly in the playback software (RV - http://www.tweaksoftware.com/products/rv), but could not get it to play faster than 20 frame per second (looking for 24 fps) with more than 3 sequences.

These playback details are a little futile, I just want to know what would be the best setup to get something like ~700MB/s read performance? Is it possible?

I've been reading quite a bit, seems like a hardware controller could be better. Also I guess 7200rpm is not enough. 10 or 15k might be better? What about SSD?

I've another constraint with this project, this machine will store all the sequences for all the projects, so density matter (I bet it will cost way more to get the same storage amount with SSD drives vs. std 10k rpm drive).

Any suggestions or tips will be appreciated to get the best read speed/storage amount.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Just stumble upon this http://www.fusionio.com/products/iodrive/. Anyone has experience with this card?

Comment: BTW, see the blog entry where the SF guys talked about making their storage decision..  http://blog.serverfault.com/post/our-storage-decision/

Comment: 23 Xeon CPUs? That a typo?

Comment: Probably HyperThreaded ... just wrote down what I got out cat /proc/cpuinfo. I'm not really a hardware guy, sorry about that. I'll need to develop on this machine eventually.

Comment: @ Zoredache It won't stream out of the network card, only locally. And thanks for that Link (:

Comment: Please be more careful with the units:
- MB means Mega Byte
- Mb means Mega bits There are 8 bits to a byte. Thus they are NOT the same.
Not knowing the conventions shows how little you know about the area. Cheers,
Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to handle video streams then you got to get something *way* better than what you spec'd. Even if you get enough SATA drives to get the desired bandwidth of 700MB/s (which should be easily doable on todays consumer class hardware) you'll maybe have sever latency problems.

What good is your storage solution if you can crank out even 1GB/s but each IO takes 500ms or so to complete? You're talking video so you want something that can deliver enough IO so that your maximum latency of 40ms (25fps) for retrieving your frames is taken care of.

You might also want to have a look at specialized file systems for video streaming applications. Hitachi Data Systems (HDS) sells one for example also XFS does have an real-time extension that was developed for media applications.

Comment: Which part should I upgrade/change besides the storage? Never heard of HDS, thanks.

Comment: Give more detailed specs - what stream and what number of streams you expect.

Comment: I think the seller for the streaming file system might be Hitachi Global Storage Solutions. They have a specialized product that can handle 14 HD streams from a single 7200 RPM disk by using a tuned IO scheduler etc.

Comment: I think the minimum would be 4 streams (2 x stereo sequences). The usual image resolution is 2K (~6MB per image)

Comment: Can you figure out your application's IO block size?

Comment: The default is 61440 bytes. The application gives me good control (but not sure I quite understand every settings) over Max Asyn Requests, I/O chunk size in bytes, I/O Method

Answer (score 5):

If you need to be able to support several consistent streams you'll either need a bunch of really fast drives (15k) or a couple of fusion IO cards or other Enterprise class SSDs.  The faster the drives the better because even those each video file is sequential on the disk, as soon as you start streaming 2 or more of them that's now a random workload which is VERY hard for the hard drives to handle.  Especially once you have 3 or more.

Comment: +1. As interim there is always the Velociraptor enterprise series which now offers 1tb drives with 10k. Well said on the random part - multiple streams of anything = random load. Point. And then it gets slow.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware raid will see more of a read benefit from raid1 than raid5, but IIRC software raid won't see a read benefit.  Someone correct me if my knowledge of mdadm is out of date.

Look for big storage vendors like EMC, IBM or even Dell.  They'll have articles on sizing storage solutions on their websites, and sometimes even simple web-apps for it.  Obviously they want to sell you things, but you can use their sizing pages to determine how many drives at what speed they suggest to get the throughput you want.

Comment: I agree about raid1, but I have to stick with RAID5 (or 10) for data security reasons.

Comment: How is the RAID level relevent to the security of the data?

Comment: http://miracleas.com/BAARF/RAID5_versus_RAID10.txt  (if one of the drive fails)

Comment: What you mean is fault tolerance, not security. RAID1 and RAID5 offer the same level of fault tolerance in that each one can survive the loss of a single array member.

Comment: On what earth does RAID1 give more _read_ performance than RAID5?!

Comment: @pfo Not saying this is faster, I'm stuck with that kind of raid.

Comment: If it's not possible to reach that kind of performance, they'll review their setup I guess.

Comment: @Xavier: RAID5 is perfect for reading large sequential data, my response was to Kyle__'s post about RAID1 having a greater "read benefit" over RAID5.

Comment: Oh, misread your answer, my bad.

Comment: joeqwerty, you said "RAID1 and RAID5 offer the same level of fault tolerance". However, Xavier stated that the spec he is working with is RAID10 or RAID5. As I'm sure you know, RAID10 provides significantly greater fault tolerance than RAID5.

Comment: Some questions: Exactly how much data are you planning on storing? What degree of availability are you looking for? I ask because, all other things being equal, SSD's would be the clear choice - except if you have many terabytes of data to serve up, wherein the cost may be prohibitive. If you are looking for the highest availability, you will want to use RAID10 - RAID5 completely blows if you lose a disk - you'll effectively be unable to serve any streams while the failed disk is rebuilt...

Comment: The use case is as follow: One user playing sequences(s) minimum 2 simultaneously, up to 4 or 6 in a theater. Hard to know how much data, but my guess would be around 4 terabytes. More than that we'll start archiving on a server to free up space. Maybe we could change our approach and store less data on that machine, but this is very unlikely due to the amount of projects/sequences that we need to have available on the fly. My main concern for now is having that realtime playback. Thanks (:

Comment: pfo, hardware raid1 can read a fraction of the bytes of data from each drive, simultaneously.  If you've only ever dealt with software raid1, you wouldn't have experienced it.

Answer (score 0):

The best overall read performance for same count and type of hard drives will be without any arrays, but your software should be aware of this configuration.

single 7200 rpm HDD gives 80-120MB/s with sequential IO.

In your case to achieve 700 MB/s you will need 700/80 = (8.75) = 9 HDDs
To add redundancy you will need 18 HDDs in RAID10 configuration.
it will cost you about $4000 with disk shelf and controller.

With SSD you can get 200-300MB/s with single SATA drive. to get 700 you will need RAID10 of 6 SATA SSDs. Price will be about $3000 (but you will have less disk space than with HDDs)

FusionIO card is capable of 700MB/s, but only when you have multiple IO threads. Single thread will get 140-150MB/s according to benchmarks.